# Java Matcher Regex Optional Group

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that I need to enhance to match an additional optional item (d_id=[Another Submit]).  Is this possible?

```
<BLOCK a_id *?= *?\"(\\d.*?)\" *?b_id *?= *?\"(.*?)\" *?c_id *?= *?\\   [(.*?)\\] *?/>

<BLOCK a_id="4273" b_id="/nyl-internet/css/form-nyl-1col-250-opt.css" c_id=[Submit]/>
```

Need to enhance the regex to also match if the optional d_id appears.

Comment: need to enhance the reggae to also match if the optional d_id appears.
    <BLOCK a_id="4273" b_id="/nyl-internet/css/form-nyl-1col-250-opt.css" c_id=[Submit] d_id=[Another Submit]/>

Comment: how thw d_id looks like.

Comment: Why are you using regex for html/xml? Wouldn't using parser be simpler? Or is `c_id=[Submit]` really part of your text which needs to be parsed which makes this xml invalid?

Comment: It's parsing something out of content, it's not valid xml.  Any chance you could explain what the part you added does?  It works!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `d_id` block inside a non-capturing group and make it as optional by adding `?` quantifier next to that group.

```
<BLOCK a_id *?= *?\"(\\d.*?)\" *?b_id *?= *?\"(.*?)\" *?c_id *?= *?\\[(.*?)\\] *?(?:d_id *?= *?\\[(.*?)\\])? *?/>
```